# In the topology,Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and let $d:X \times X \to[0,+ ∞)$ be a function defined by formulas

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{1,2,3\}$ and let $d:X \times X \to[0,+\infty)$ be a function defined by formulas:
$$
d(1,1)=d(2,2)=d(3,3)=0,\\
d(1,2)=d(2,1)=d(1,3)=d(3,1)=1,\\
d(2,3)=d(3,2)=3.$$

Check if $d$ is a distance function on $X$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you remember the definition of distance functions?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math.SE! In this community, when posting a question, you are encouraged to include in the body of the question some of your thoughts about the problem, some context about it. Check this [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for some information about posting good questions.

Comment: Yes  I have 3 or 4 rules for this questions, but I can not be sure....Could you help me and explain the questions and answer ?

Answer (score 2):

To check that $d$ is a distance on $X$ you need: 
1) $d(x,y)\geq 0$ $\forall x,y \in X$ and $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$ 
2) $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$ $\forall x,y \in X$ 
3) $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$ $\forall x,y,z \in X$

The first line of formulas gives you 1), the second line gives you 2), but then 
$3=d(2,3) \leq d(2,1)+d(1,3)=1+1=2$ and that is a contradiction. Therefore $d$ is not a distance